# Java Regex match space before or after characters

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, whitespace, wildcard

I try to have a regex validating an input field.

This question is the continuation of **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783464/java-regex-with-joker-characters)** but I made a mistake and the question changed a bit so I created a new one.

Here is my java regex :

```
^(?:\?*[a-zA-Z\d]){2}[a-zA-Z\d?]*\*?$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wimr5R/6)**

What I'm tying to match is :

- Minimum 2 alpha-numeric characters (other than '?' and '*')
- The '*' can only appears one time and at the end of the string
- The '?' can appears multiple time
- No WhiteSpace right at the beginning
- No WhiteSpace before or after '?' or '*'

> ### So for exemple :
>
> - abcd = OK
> - ?bcd = OK
> - ab?? = OK
> - ab*= OK
> - ab?* = OK
> - ??cd = OK
> - ab cd = OK
> - *ab = NOT OK
> - a ? b =NOT OK
> - ??? = NOT OK
> - ab? cd = NOT OK
> - ab ?d = NOT OK
> - ab * = NOT OK
> - abcd = NOT OK (space at the begining)

As i've asked in the fisrt question, no white space at all are allowed in my regex now but that's not what I want and I'm a bit lost can you help me please?

Comment: Would `a b`(with a space in the middle) be OK? Would `a?b` (without space)?

Comment: Yes (a?b = ok)  (ab cd=ok) (a bcd=ok) (a b=ok)

Comment: **one** or **multiple** space is OK but not right before or right after '*' or '?' and not at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!\s)(?!.*\s[*?])(?!.*[*?]\s)(?:[?\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2}[a-zA-Z0-9?\s]*\*?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXpFDd/1).

*Usage note*: if you use it with Java's `.matches()` method, the `^` and `$` can be removed from the pattern. Remember to double escape backslashes in the string literal.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s)` - no whitespace is allowed immediately to the right (at the start of the string)
- `(?!.*\s[*?])` - no whitespace is allowed after any 0+ chars, as many as possible, before `*` or `?`
- `(?!.*[*?]\s)` - no whitespace is allowed after any 0+ chars, as many as possible, after `*` or `?`
- `(?:[?\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2}` - two sequences of

  - `[?\s]*` - 0 or more `?` or/and whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9?\s]*` - 0 or more letters, digits, `?` or whitespaces
- `\*?` - an optional `?` char
- `$` - end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Could'nt be better!